# tinymce ad image unable to select the folder

Tags: jquery, tinymce

When I click on the insert image on the insert/edit image, I don't have the "select from folder" button. Here is my code:

```
    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : 'tinymce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
        language : "he",
        mode: "textareas",
        directionality : "rtl",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,table,advimage,advhr,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,directionality,noneditable,visualchars,xhtmlxtras,advlist,advimage,",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "undo,redo,|,preview,|,search,replace,|,forecolor,backcolor,fontsizeselect,fontselect,|,strikethrough,underline,italic,bold",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,cleanup,code,|,removeformat,sub,sup,styleprops,|,cite,link,unlink,image,charmap,iespell,hr,insertdate,inserttime,",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,ltr,rtl,|,outdent,indent,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "right",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    });
```

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to integrate the imagemanager and/or filemanager plugin.

See this enlightening thread in [the tinymce forum](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=24769).

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertfile,insertimage",
```